# Write Cache in php

Tags: php, caching, yii, memcached

I need to store the content array in cache, using the provided key. Add current unix timestamp as array element ‘created’. Can someone check my code if it is correct or not!

```
public function writeToCache($key, $content) {
    $this->cacheExtension = new DateTime;

    $file = fopen($this->cacheLocation . $key . $this->cacheExtension->format("y:m:d h:i:s"), "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
    fwrite($file, $content); 
    fclose($file);
}
```

Comment: As you cannot create a file with `:` in its name, your code will not work.

Comment: Can you help to modify the code?

Answer (score 0):

I solve the problem. I was dumb!

```
public function writeToCache($key, $content) {
$date = new DateTime();
$date = $date->format("yy-mm-dd");

$file = fopen($this->cacheLocation . $key . "_created_" . $date, "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
fwrite($file, json_encode($content)); 
fclose($file);}
```